# Sony Spresense で sigfox は利用できる？

Tags: arduino, spresense

spresense で Sigfox Shield for Arduino は、利用できますか？

Answer (score 2):

最近、Spresense向けのSigfoxボードが発売になったようですね。
遅レスですが、こちらはSpresenseでの動作確認がされているようです。

https://www.smk.co.jp/products/EM-WF931-02F/

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答いたします。

残念ながら、Sigfox Shield for Arduino との組み合わせ動作は確認しておりません。

どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらの回答は、公式のサポートとしては確認していない、つまり、動くかもしれないけれど確認はされていない、ということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。言葉足らずで失礼をいたしました。